# How can I extract a string and number from a larger based on a unique pattern in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Given the following string structure:

```
Mark;12345 wrote:    // Username = Mark   ID# = 12345
```

```
Alex-Johnson;747645 wrote:       // Username = Alex-Johnson   ID# = 747645
```

```
Felix@felix.com;83213 wrote:    // Username = Felix@felix.com   ID# = 83213
```

```
Jack65;123123 wrote:      // Username = Jack65   ID# = 123123
```

```
John wrote:      // Username = John   ID# = null
```

Id like to ideally extract the username and the userid, which are going to be separated by a `;`.   There may also be times when the ID# will be blank as in the last example string

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## // You can try this code. Here I used  null-safety, regexp ,list and maps

```
    void main()
    {

    String str = '''Mark;12345
    Alex-Johnson;747645
    Felix@felix.com;83213
    Jack65;123123
    John
    Bill
    ;1111''';

  Map<String?,String?> lineMaped= {};
  //This map will receive the username and the userid
  List<String> listOfEachLine= str.split('\n');
  //Each line of the text is put in the list

  RegExp searchForName= new RegExp(r'([\w._@-]+)(?:[;])([\d]*)');
  //this RegExp only have a match when the line has an ';' and a letter or digit 
  //before 
   for (int i=0;i < listOfEachLine.length;i++){
     RegExpMatch? match = searchForName.firstMatch(listOfEachLine[i]);
     //the firstMatch method can return null, for this situation I use the '?' 
       //in type declaration
     if(';'.allMatches(listOfEachLine[i]).length == 0){      
       //condition: there isn't any ';' in the line, in other words: when  ID# 
       //is blank
     lineMaped.addAll({listOfEachLine[i] : ''}); 
     } else {
         if (match != null && match.groupCount>1) { 
           //this if ensures the non-nullable of variables
         lineMaped.addAll({match.group(1): match.group(2)});
         
         } //if
       } //else
   }  //for
     lineMaped.forEach((k,v) => print('\n ${k} <-> ${v}'));
 } //main
```

//Output:

//Mark <-> 12345

//Alex-Johnson <-> 747645

//Felix@felix.com <-> 83213

//Jack65 <-> 123123

//John <->

//Bill <->

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with a substring. You can also do it with a split I think.

```
String text = 'Mark;12457 wrote:';
   if(text.contains(';')){
      int size = text.indexOf(';'); 
      int size2= text.indexOf('wrote:');
      String userName = text.substring(0,size);
      String id = text.substring(size+1,size2); //1 is the number of character in ('...')
      print('username: $userName, id#: $id');
  }else{
      int size= text.indexOf('wrote:');
      String userName = text.substring(0,size);
      print('username: $userName, id#: null');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

much simplier

```
var str = 'Mark;12345 wrote:';
final arr = str.replaceAll(' wrote:', '').split(';');
final userName = arr[0];
final userId = arr.length > 1 ? arr[1] : null;
print('$userName   $userId');
```